# Laravel foreach total price of all products

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

In Laravel, if I want to get the total price of all products in the cart, what should I add to my code? This is the cart.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<main class="container">

  <section class="row justify-content-center">

   <h1 class="text-center mb-5">Products on your cart:</h1>

  </section>

  <section class="row justify-content-center">

  @foreach(Auth::user()->computers()->get() as $computer)

  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">

   <h2 class="text-center">{{$computer->name}}</h2>
   <img class="card-img-top" src="{{Storage::url($computer->img)}}" alt="">
   <form action="{{route('computers.removepc',['id'=>$computer->id])}}" method="POST">
   @csrf 
   <center><button class="btn btn-danger mb-5" type="submit">Remove</button></center>
   <p class="text-center">Price: {{$computer->price}}</p> //This is the single price of each product

   </div>

 @endforeach


 </section>

 <section class="row justify-content-center">
  <h1>Here I want the total price</h1> //Here is , for example, where i want the total price of all computers in the cart
 </section>

 </main>
 @endsection
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: try `Auth::user()->computers->sum('price');`. Note that there are no () in computers.

Comment: Doesn't work, returns me error: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: You can use Auth::user()->withCount(‘computers’)->get();

Comment: Is computers a relation in your user model? If so, it must be a collection and `->sum` should work on it. Try `Auth::user()->computers()->get()->sum('price');` with () on computers.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add $total varibale above @foreach, like this:

```
<?php $total = 0; ?>
```

Then inside @foreach add the following:

```
 <?php $total+= $computer->price  ?>
```

Then go to the place you want to output the total and write:

```
   {{$total}}
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you don't mind mark it as correct.